# Is there any way to pass props to component without calling it

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-props

I have 3 components like: Parent, First-child and Second-child. And I am iterating First-child in Parent component in array(it is cards), and I want to call Second-child in Parent component with First-child's props(props of one card).

My Parent component looks like this(how I am calling First-child):

``

```html
<CardComponent
   v-for="card of cards"
   :key="card.urlsId"
   :cardImages="card.images"
   :cardTitle="card.title"
   :cardDescription="card.description"
   :mediaRef="card.urlsId"
   :dbRef="card.dbId"
   :deleteBtn="true"
   :imagesWithSlider="true"
 />
```

And my First child is:

```html
<template>
  <div class="cards">
    <v-card class="card-container">
      <div class="delete-btn">
        <v-btn
          v-if="deleteBtn"
          class="mx-2"
          fab
          dark
          small
          @click="$emit('onOpenDeleteModal')"
        >
          <v-icon dark> mdi-delete </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
      <ImageSlider
        v-if="imagesWithSlider"
        :imagesArray="cardImages"
        :arrowBtns="false"
      />
      <div class="text-container">
        <h3 class="card-title">{{ cardTitle }}</h3>
        <p class="card-description">{{ cardDescription }}</p>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    cardImages: {
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },
    cardTitle: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Title',
    },
    cardDescription: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Description',
    },
    deleteBtn: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    imagesWithSlider: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    mediaRef: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    dbRef: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    deleteModalOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
  emits: ['onOpenDeleteModal', 'onCloseDeleteModal'],
}
</script>
```

And my Second-child is:

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="modal" :loading="newCard.loading ? true : false">
    <v-card class="modal-header">
      <h3 v-if="addCardModal" class="header-title">New card</h3>
      <h3 v-if="deleteModal" class="header-title">Delete</h3>
      <v-icon aria-hidden="false" width="100%" @click="$emit('closeModal')"
        >mdi-close</v-icon
      >
    </v-card>

    <!-- Delete Modal  -->
    <div v-if="deleteModal" class="modal-delete">
      <h3>Are you really want to delete this card ?</h3>
      <div class="modal-delete-btns">
        <v-btn @click="$emit('closeModal')">Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="error" @click="$emit('onDeleteCard')">Delete</v-btn>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add New Card Modal  -->
    <form
      v-if="addCardModal"
      class="modal-container"
      @submit.prevent="postNewCardToDb"
    >
      <v-file-input
        v-model="newCard.cardImages"
        :clearable="false"
        multiple
        show-size
        label="Upload card images"
        @change="previewImage"
      >
      </v-file-input>
      <v-file-input
        v-model="newCard.cardVideo"
        :clearable="false"
        show-size
        label="Upload video"
      >
      </v-file-input>
      <div v-if="newCard.cardImageUrls.length !== 0" class="preview-image">
        <ImageSlider :imagesArray="newCard.cardImageUrls" :arrowBtns="true" />
      </div>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="newCard.cardTitle"
        label="Enter card title"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="newCard.cardSnippet"
        label="Enter card description"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-btn type="submit" :loading="newCard.loading ? true : false" block
        >POST</v-btn
      >
    </form>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import { v4 as uuidV4, v1 as uuidV1 } from 'uuid'

export default {
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  props: {
    addCardModal: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    deleteModal: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
  emits: ['closeModal', 'onDeleteCard'],
  data() {
    return {
      newCard: {
        loading: false,
        cardImages: [],
        cardVideo: null,
        cardImageUrls: [],
        cardTitle: '',
        cardSnippet: '',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    previewImage($event) {
      for (const image of event.target.files) {
        this.newCard.cardImageUrls.push(URL.createObjectURL(image))
      }
    },

    async getMediaUrlsFromStorage(newCardData) {
      const cardMediaRef = uuidV1()
      const cardImagesRef = await this.$fire.storage
        .ref('/albums_cards/')
        .child(cardMediaRef)
      const videoRef = await cardImagesRef.child(uuidV4())
      if (this.newCard.cardVideo) {
        await videoRef.put(this.newCard.cardVideo)
        const videoUrl = await videoRef.getDownloadURL()
        newCardData.video = videoUrl
      }
      newCardData.urlsId = cardMediaRef
      const promiseArr = this.newCard.cardImages.map(async (image) => {
        const imageRef = cardImagesRef.child(uuidV4())
        await imageRef.put(image)
        const imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL()
        newCardData.images.push(imageUrl)
      })
      await Promise.all(promiseArr)
    },

    async postNewCardToDb() {
      this.newCard.loading = true

      const newCardData = {
        urlsId: '',
        title: this.newCard.cardTitle,
        description: this.newCard.cardSnippet,
        video: '',
        images: [],
      }

      await this.getMediaUrlsFromStorage(newCardData)

      await this.$fire.database.ref('albums/cards').push(newCardData)
      console.log(newCardData)

      this.newCard.loading = false
      this.newCard.cardTitle = null
      this.newCard.cardSnippet = null
      this.newCard.cardImages = []
      this.newCard.cardImageUrls = []
      this.newCard.cardVideo = null
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

First-child is a card component and I need to pass props of each card to Second-child without calling it. I cant call Second-child in First-child because of iteration.

I hope I expleined it well

Comment: @kissu, Firstly I want to thank you, you always help me. Almost in every my question you answer, and I think in this also, It is a little messed here but I really tried to explain my question. Please, text me if anything is not enough to answer the question

Comment: PS: if you `@kissu` me while I didn't interact with a question, I will not get notified. I'm just passing by here so that you know that `@kissu` has no effect prior to my venue. Now the question: I am not good at understanding something with just words. Regarding the title, I'd say "no". But a visual explanation may greatly help us. Otherwise, a [repro] with the least amount of code possible (so that it's scoped and relevant) seems to be quite mandatory here too. Right now, there are too many things going on, I have no visibility regarding the shape of the data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I know that you dont get notified. I just guessed that you will see this question